# Print type of variable in python3.5 on django 1.8

Tags: django, python-3.5

I am having a hard time of determining the type of my variable since I am used on python2 and have just migrated to python3

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def myview(request):
    x = "Name"
    print (x)
    print type(x)
    return HttpResponse("Example output")
```

This code will throw an error because of print type(x). However if you changed that syntax line  to type(x). The type does not return an output on the runserver of django.

Comment: Look into the IPDB pip package. It allows you to interact with your code while in runtime and go through it one line at a time. You have an interactive terminal and can type "type(x)" at any point in the code to see your variable types and data.. TRUST me it will save you countless hours when debugging.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`print` in Python 3 is no longer a statement, but a function. You need to call it using parentheses:

```
print(type(x))
```